# update action for multiple forms on an edit page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, simple-form

I have a page in which a user can upload a job.  On the edit page, I have a loop that goes through all existing jobs and prints a form for each job.  The problem is, I don't know how to tell the update action in the controller which job to update.  Here is the edit page:

```
<% @currentjobs.each do |thejob| %>
  <%= simple_form_for(thejob) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <%= f.input :firm, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "Firm" %> <br>
      <%= f.input :position, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "Position" %> <br>
      <%= f.input :category, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "Category"%>
      <%= f.input :begin, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "Beginning", collection: 1960..2013 %><br>
      <%= f.input :end, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "End", collection: 1960..2013 %>
      <%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'field' }, label: "Description"%>

         <div class="form-actions">
           <%= f.submit "Save" %>
         </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the update action:

```
def update
        thejob = current_user.profile.jobs.where(:id => params[:id])
        thejob.update_attributes(job_params)
        flash[:success] = "You have succesfully updated your info"
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
end
```

I know it has something to do with the update action where I call the form.  I think I'm calling the wrong thing.

UPDATE:  Here are the forms that are generated by this view (keep in mind no style):

[image: Edit View Page]

And here is my routes code for jobs:

```
  resources :jobs
```

And here is the html generated by rails:

```
   <h1>edit page for jobs </h1>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs/9" class="simple_form edit_job" id="edit_job_9" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="woHDLDSOUhEA6AZU1TDVbOVW1el6lUVL3evDF/svInc=" /></div>


      <div class="input string required job_firm"><label class="string required" for="job_firm"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Firm</label><input aria-required="true" class="string required fsield" id="job_firm" maxlength="80" name="job[firm]" required="required" size="80" type="text" value="alan iverson falkjf kjfh fsdlkjh " /></div> <br>
      <div class="input string required job_position"><label class="string required" for="job_position"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Position</label><input aria-required="true" class="string required fsield" id="job_position" maxlength="80" name="job[position]" required="required" size="80" type="text" value="position 3" /></div> <br>
      <div class="input string optional job_category"><label class="string optional" for="job_category">Category</label><input class="string optional fsield" id="job_category" maxlength="255" name="job[category]" size="255" type="text" value="" /></div>
      <div class="input select required job_begin"><label class="select required" for="job_begin"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Beginning</label><select aria-required="true" class="select required fsield" id="job_begin" name="job[begin]" required="required"><option value=""></option>
      <option value="1960">1960</option>
      <option value="1961">1961</option>
      .
      .
      .
      <div class="input select required job_end"><label class="select required" for="job_end"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> End</label><select aria-required="true" class="select required fsield" id="job_end" name="job[end]" required="required"><option value=""></option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1960">1960</option>
      <option value="1961">1961</option>
      .
      .
      .
      <div class="input text required job_description"><label class="text required" for="job_description"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Description</label><textarea aria-required="true" class="text required fsield" id="job_description" maxlength="500" name="job[description]" required="required">
      </textarea></div>

  <div class="form-actions">
       <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
  </div><br><br>
</form>


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs/7" class="simple_form edit_job" id="edit_job_7" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="woHDLDSOUhEA6AZU1TDVbOVW1el6lUVL3evDF/svInc=" /></div>
      <div class="input string required job_firm"><label class="string required" for="job_firm"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Firm</label><input aria-required="true" class="string required fsield" id="job_firm" maxlength="80" name="job[firm]" required="required" size="80" type="text" value="asf asd fasf asd fas as fsaf sd" /></div> <br>
      <div class="input string required job_position"><label class="string required" for="job_position"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Position</label><input aria-required="true" class="string required fsield" id="job_position" maxlength="80" name="job[position]" required="required" size="80" type="text" value="position 2" /></div> <br>
      <div class="input string optional job_category"><label class="string optional" for="job_category">Category</label><input class="string optional fsield" id="job_category" maxlength="255" name="job[category]" size="255" type="text" value="fafdsfds" /></div>
      <div class="input select required job_begin"><label class="select required" for="job_begin"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Beginning</label><select aria-required="true" class="select required fsield" id="job_begin" name="job[begin]" required="required"><option value=""></option>
      .
      .
      .

      <div class="input text required job_description"><label class="text required" for="job_description"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Description</label><textarea aria-required="true" class="text required fsield" id="job_description" maxlength="500" name="job[description]" required="required">
      </textarea></div>

         <div class="form-actions">
           <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
         </div><br><br>
</form>
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can do that via an id parameter in URL. Your form's action attribute, should have value like 'domain.com/jobs/:id' and method PUT or PATCH. Thanks to the job id, Rails know which job should be updated. But your code look ok? What exactly is your problem? What happens, when you try to update a job?

Comment: Im pretty sure :id in the update action refers to the id in the url.  I need to somehow refer to the id number of the job that the user is updating.

Comment: When I try to update a job, I get this error:   'undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Job:0x007f8da290f948>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to make things clear, check out the code generated by simple_form. It will generate multiple forms with action attribute, where the value of this attribute will be something like 'domain.com/jobs/job_id'. When you submit the form, it will issue an PUT or PATCH request on the URL from action attribute and that's how Rails know, which job to update - because you tell it, in the URL.

And the reason this is not working for you, is because you are trying to call method 'update_attributes' on Relation object, not on job. Try this:

```
thejob = current_user.profile.jobs.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

Or even better:

```
thejob = current_user.profile.jobs.find(params[:id)
```

**Edit** Example:

jobs_controller.rb: (I'm using index action to render the forms, but you can use whichever action you want, just don't use edit - it's supposed to be used for editing single resource.)

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.update_attributes(job_params)
      redirect_to jobs_path
    else
      render :index
    end
  end

  private

    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
# if you will use index action to render forms
resources :jobs


# if you want to use some custom action to render forms
# in this case add multiedit action to the jobs_controller
# and create a view for it
resources :jobs do
  get 'multiedit'
end
```

and view (in my case index.html.erb):

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= simple_form_for(job) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>  
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now, the view will render something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs/1" class="simple_form edit_job" id="edit_job_1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
    .
    .
    .
</form>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs/2" class="simple_form edit_job" id="edit_job_1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Both of these forms, will be submitted to jobs#update action, but the first one with params[:id] == 1 and the second one with params[:id] == 2. And this is, what you need, to know which object is being updated. Hope it's clear now...

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it will take whatever job I update and won't update it.  Instead, it updates the last job with the information.  The url can't tell it which job to update.  The page has 4 forms on it, each corresponding to a different job.  I need the update method to see which job the filled in form corresponds to and to change that one.  The url simply goes to the edit page for all jobs.  I realize, after seeing your answer, that maybe I have my route set up incorrectly for this?  If thats the case, how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you please post the forms generated by simple_form_for in your edit view? And also post your route.rb.

Comment: OK just posted them.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the routes. By forms generated by simple_form, I meant HTML source code of the forms, not actual HTML page.

Comment: Oh ok, I will post that now.

Comment: I added the first two forms.  It takes a lot of editing to paste it into stack overflow.  If you want me to paste the rest, please let me know.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, and do you see: action="/jobs/9" and action="/jobs/7"? That is how  Rails will know which job to update. Hold on a sec, I will update my answer with example.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this.  For some reason, it is doing one of two things:  It is either deleting job 1 and replacing the last job with the new job, or, it is updating the first job and then moving it to the bottom of the show page (my guess is because it is the most recently updated).  Either way, it is not updating the right job.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's really strange. Anyway I'm sure the code I posted works. Try debugging (i like using Pry https://github.com/pry/pry), your code. Check if job object is valid when you trying to update it...